# Insertar caracter en una cadena de texto

Tags: javascript, string

Tengo que los codigos postales ingleses tienen el formato `X1 1XX`,`XX1 1XX` o `XX11 1XX`

Y a mi me vienen juntos, de manera `X11XX`, `XX11XX` y `XX111XX`. Y necesito mostrar con el formato espaciado.

Entonces el tema es que necesito poner un espacio la posicion `string.length -3`

```js
addr = 'T11DH';
addr =  (addr).slice(0, 2) + " " + (addr).slice(2);
console.log(addr)

addr = 'TN11DH';
addr =  (addr).slice(0, 3) + " " + (addr).slice(3);
console.log(addr)

addr = 'TN131DH';
addr =  (addr).slice(0, 4) + " " + (addr).slice(4);
console.log(addr)
```

Como veis, si hago `slice`, necesito cambiar el tamaño que necesito cortar dependiendo de la longitud de la cadena.

```
switch(addr.length){
   case 5:
       addr =  (addr).slice(0, 2) + " " + (addr).slice(2);  
       break;
   case 6:  
       addr =  (addr).slice(0, 3) + " " + (addr).slice(3);  
       break;
   case 7:  
       addr =  (addr).slice(0, 4) + " " + (addr).slice(4);  
       break;
}
```

Me parece que es demasiado código, y que tiene que haber una manera mas eficiente. Pero no se me ocurre ninguna.

Comment: `X` ¿puede ser numérico o alfanumérico?

Comment: `X` no es numérico, es siempre `[A-Z]`, los `1` siempre son numéricos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string` no te ofrece ninguna funcionalidad para introducir una caracter en una posición específica; basta con ver el API.

Dicho esto, siempre hay opciones de optimizar:

- hacer una función

  ```
  function arreglarCP(var addr, var posicion) {
     return addr.slice(0, posicion) + " " + (addr).slice(posicion);  
  }

  ....
  addr = arreglarCP(addr, 2);
  ```
- el switch no parece muy necesario:

  ```
  addr = arreglarCP(addr, addr.length - 3);
  ```
- debido a las restricciones del formato, te basta con sustituir el "11" por "1 1":

  ```
  addr = addr.replace("11", "1 1");
  ```

De todas formas, salvo que sea por el "aprender a hacer las cosas de forma distinta", este tipo de "micro-optimizaciones"<sup>1</sup> generalmente no valen la pena.

---

<sup>1</sup> No, nada de esto mejorará de manera apreciable el rendimiento de tu sistema.

Comment: Sinceramente el segundo punto me parece interesante. directamente pasarle la longitud -3.  Mas que la optimizacion, es lo legible que sea el codigo. Ya que cuando tratas con archivos de +1000 lineas, cualquier ahorro resulta importante. Al menos en mi caso.

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo una solución con substring:

```
const cpFormateado = addr.substring(0, addr.length - 3)
   + ' '
   + addr.substring(addr.length - 3, addr.length);
```

Comment: buscaba algo similar y gracias a tu código pude construir esto:
//value = "9" o "9.8"
var valueTrue = value.replace(".","");
valueTrue = valueTrue.substr(0,1) + '.' + valueTrue.substr(1,valueTrue.length);